# Downloading large files from S3 with snakemake

Tags: snakemake

I am making a workflow in snakemake 5.8.2 which takes as an input huge files from S3 (280Gb each of 4 files). The first rule just concatenates the files.
When I run the workflow, it seems to download only 5GB of some split version of each file, delete the file and fails to concatenate. I know aws transfers files in 5GB batches but I expected snakemake to handle this in the background.
Am I missing something? Is this a bug?
Thanks,
Ilya.

Comment: Please share some code, we can not help you without a better description.

Comment: Since the data is not public, any code I would share would be useless. A minimal example would be to try and use a large file from S3 as input for a snakemake rule.

Comment: Did downloading a large (public) file work?

Comment: I didn't try because I don't know of public data sets stored on S3. Do you know about such data sets?

Comment: [Tabula Muris Senis](https://s3.console.aws.amazon.com/s3/buckets/czb-tabula-muris-senis). Here's a 22GB file you could test: `"czb-tabula-muris-senis/10x/24_month/MACA_24m_M_PANCREASE_EXO_60/possorted_genome_bam.bam"`

Comment: I got it to work with a different file of mine. It seems that the issue was caused by me using a wildcard for the file suffix. That confused snakemake because the file is appended an additional suffix when being downloaded from s3.